# Не получается отправить HTTP запрос на сервлет через XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, java, java-ee, servlet, xmlhttprequest

Запрос пытаюсь отправить так:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            document.location.replace("#x");
        };
};
xhr.open('POST', 'localhost:8080/MyLay/Message', true);
xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHandler("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(null);
```

Вот сервлет:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    mail.send("MyLay", "text", "astrgan@gmail.com", null);
    response.getWriter().println("HellofromServlet");


}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

[Весь код java](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0PxTR5NzjFhV09sbDV1OGhkX2M)

[Весь код html](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0PxTR5NzjFheHFQTUxVWHJ5Tlk)

Comment: опубликуйте код здесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий пример кода из моего проекта. Используйте Jquery.. И просмотрите что выводится в консоле браузера, по какой причине не получается ?

```js
$("#register-button").click(function () {

    var user = {

        firstName:$("[name=firstname]").val(),
        lastName:$("[name=lastname]").val(),
        nickName:$("[name=nickname]").val(),
        email:$("[name=email]").val(),
        password:$("[name=password]").val(),
        customerType:$("[name=customertype]").val(),
        formId:$("#formId").val()
    }

    var JSONString = JSON.stringify(user);

    var url = "http://localhost:8080/CouponProject/register";

    $.ajax({

        url:url,
        method:"post",
        data:JSONString,
        contentType:"application/json",
        error:function (message) {

            var JSONObject = JSON.parse(message);
            console.log(JSONObject);

        },
        success:function (data) {

            var JSONObject = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(JSONObject);

        },
        headers:
        {
            "Accept":"application/json",
            "Accept-Language":"en",
            "Cache-Control":"max-age=3600"
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="register-page" id = "register-page">

          <div class="register-panel">

              <div class="form-register-div">

                  <form>

                      <label for="first-name">First Name:</label>
                      <input id = "first-name" name="firstname" type="text"><br>
                      <label for = "last-name">Last Name:</label>
                      <input id = "last-name" name="lastname" type="text"><br>
                      <label for = "nick_name">Nick Name:</label>
                      <input id = "nick_name" name="nickname" type="text"><br>
                      <label for="email_">Email:</label>
                      <input id = "email_" name="email" type="email"><br>
                      <label for="password_">Password:</label>
                      <input id="password_" name="password" type="password"><br>
                      <label for = "cust-type">Customer Type:</label>
                      <input id = "cust-type" name="customertype" type="text"><br>
                      <input type="hidden" id="formId" value="register">
                      <input value="Register" type="button" id = "register-button">

                  </form>

              </div>

          </div>
```

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/register")
public class Register extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
    writer.print("Hello");
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    ResponseDataHandler.setHeaders(this.getClass(),resp);

    User user = new RegisterRequestDataHandler().getRegisterConvertedData(req);

  }
 }
```